# How to use logUsage flag to shell.openExternal() in Electron?

Tags: windows, electron, shellexecuteex

Electron 24 has added a flag `logUsage` to `shell.openExternal()` but is not very clear to me, when it should be (or should not be) used?

From [Electron.js 24 Release Notes](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-24-0#new-features):

> Added `logUsage` to `shell.openExternal()` options, which allows passing the `SEE_MASK_FLAG_LOG_USAGE` flag to `ShellExecuteEx` on Windows. The `SEE_MASK_FLAG_LOG_USAGE` flag indicates a user initiated launch that enables tracking of frequently used programs and other behaviors.

All actions are directly or indirectly user initiated in a typical app. So, it seems to me, the flag should be `logUsage: true` always. The question is, when to set the flag to `false`? E.g. these use cases when `shell.openExternal()` may be executed:

- User action to open URL from her data (content) - it clear that `logUsage: true`.
- User action to open internal app help. The app author decides that the help is in external files and also decides format of these files (PDF, HTML, ...). So, the action is user initiated, but it's a kind of internal app stuff. Should be `logUsage: false` in this case?
- Other app action examples where should be `logUsage: false`?

(Windows [SHELLEXECUTEINFOA structure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) is not much helpful neither.)